# rails 3.1 - how to do an easy query with associations (all orders for a user, through accounts)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

```
Users has_many Accounts
Accounts belongs_to Users

Accounts has_many Orders
Orders belongs_to Account
```

I am trying to get a list of all the orders for a user 'u'

As expected, u.accounts gives a list of all the accounts for that user

u.accounts.joins(:orders) is incorrect, since it lists stores, not orders (seems to list the store for each order, rather than the order for each order)

Is a user has 3 accounts, and each account has 4 orders, I should have 12 rows.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In user.rb:

```
has_many :orders, :through => :accounts
```

Then you should be able to just do u.orders.